# How to include angular syntax in Razor

Tags: angularjs, razor

Can Angular syntax be included in Razor:

In the code below I am trying to say if "p.name" is not equal to "Select All"  display an image but I dont think I can include {{p.name}} in the if statement

```
<div ng-repeat="p in Data.platforms">
    <div style="font-size: smaller">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="p.selected" />

        @if ("p.name" != "Select All") {
            <img ng-src="{{'/Content/img/'+p.name+'.jpg'}}" width="16" height="16" alt="{{p.name}}" />
        } 

        {{p.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no you can't use values in javascript variables for razor (which renders server-side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Razor you are comparing two strings that will never be equal.  `"p.name" != "Select All"` will always be `true`.

This all takes place before angular.

In angular you can use `ng-show`

```
<div ng-repeat="p in Data.platforms">
    <div style="font-size: smaller">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="p.selected" />
        <img ng-show="p.name != 'Select All'" ng-src="{{'/Content/img/'+p.name+'.jpg'}}" width="16" height="16" alt="{{p.name}}" />
        {{p.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that since Razor has no idea about what the value of `p.name` evaluates.

However you can achieve it with AngularJS

```
<img ng-show="p.name!= 'Select All'" ng-src="{{'/Content/img/'+p.name+'.jpg'}}" width="16" height="16" alt="{{p.name}}" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it will always show the image.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18768940/1873485 for more details as to why.